# exchange 2013 powershell shows only exchange 2010 databases

Tags: powershell, migration, exchange-server

I have two ex2010 and two ex2013 installed in my organization.
Everything works fine but on one of the ex2013 servers then I run

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MailboxDatabase

Name                           Server          Recovery        ReplicationType
----                           ------          --------        ---------------
archive1                       EXCH02          False           Remote
mdb03                          EXCH02          False           Remote
mdb04                          EXCH02          False           Remote
mdb02                          EXCH02          False           Remote
mdb05                          EXCH02          False           None
```

I only have ex2010 databases listed.
Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange 2010/2013 co-existence environment you have to use this command :

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -IncludePreExchange2013
```

You will have a list of all  Databases for Exchange 2013 and prior versions.

Comment: There is no need to run this command since I have problem with showing up 2013 databases on one of 2013 servers (call it exch03). There other one works pretty fine (call it exch01). Further investigation showed that exch03 loads 2010 commanlets. I think that's a problem but can't manage to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. That was an CU11 for exchange 2013 issue, please refer to [Microsoft explanation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2015/12/15/exchange-management-shell-and-mailbox-anchoring.aspx)